# How can I use a widely-available cross-platform command line program to render a string containing emoji

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, fonts, imagemagick

I would like to use a widely-available command line program, the lighter-weight the better, to render a string containing emoji into a raster image. The rules are:

- must work on a minimum of OS X and Linux. Windows is a bonus
- must be available from both homebrew and apt

  - and work in its default configuration from both
  - this eliminates imagemagick + pango, for example - homebrew builds im without it)
- must not require a full programming language environment (i.e. no "pip install" or "npm install"ing anything)
- must not require a browser

  - if you can come up with a short way to do this with a browser that doesn't ask me to ask users to install puppeteer, it's marginally acceptable.
  - but I would like something much lighter weight than this
- must render full color emoji
- must use system fonts, no asking a user to install or muck around with their fonts

Things I've tried:

### ImageMagick

`convert -background lightblue -fill blue -pointsize 72 "label:Hot  stuff" png:- | imgcat`

[image: some text with missing emoji]

- I'm aware that imagemagic can be built with pango and apparently this will work, but it's not by default on homebrew, and I don't want to require users of my program to install a custom build

### rsvg-convert

I was really hopeful for this one! Unfortunately:

`echo '<svg viewBox="0 0 450 80"><text x="0" y="80" fill="#ff0000" font-size="80">Some  text</text></svg>'  | rsvg-convert  | imgcat`

[image: some text with missing emoji]

### ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -ss 1:57 -to 2:00 -copyts -i /tmp/ytgif_cache/video_httpswwwyoutubecomwatchvnrqxmQruto.webm -filter_complex '[0:v] fps=10, scale=640:-1, split [a][b], [a] palettegen [p], [b][p] paletteuse, drawtext=borderw=1:bordercolor=black:fontcolor=white:fontsize=30:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)-10:text= flames ' flames.gif
```

[image: flames scene from clue but the emoji don't render]

### What have you got

That's all I've tried, and I'm kind of out of ideas! It feels like this should not be a challenging thing to do, as all the software I use day to day does renders emoji effortlessly. What else could I be using?

Surely *something* works to handle this?

Comment: I think this is a better fit for [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I think it's extremely unlikely to be successful there, but I've asked: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/87459/what-widely-available-cross-platform-command-line-program-can-i-use-to-render-a

Comment: That maybe so, but it is off-topic here.  You have only asked there today.